# Writing text with maximum length in Apache POI to cell

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

For an application I have to test if a text will fit into a cell in Apache POI.

To test some things quickly, I wrote a small demo application, where I wrote the maximal allowed amount of characters to a cell. I encountered that the number of characters I could write to a cell

So, this is the demo application:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Test");

for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(idx);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(StringUtils.repeat("-", wb.getSpreadsheetVersion().getMaxTextLength()));
}

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.xls");
wb.write(out);

out.close();
wb.close();
```

But when opening the created excel file, I failed to read the cells I've written to, prompting that the cell could only contain between 1 and 255 characters. But this is different than what I get from "wb.getSpreadsheetVersion().getMaxTextLength()". Does some characters in the text require some special treatment? Note that when writing more than 255 times "-" directly into excel, I do not have any problems.

Using "*" instead of "-" works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Limitation of characters in Excel cell - **32767** (2^15-1)
- Limitation of characters in Excel cell with formula - **255** (2^8-1)

Thus, if your first character is `=` or `+` you go for the lower limit.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the max formula limitation? For the basic cell it is SpreadsheetVersion#getMaxCellLength, but for a formula cell no such method seems to be available. EDIT: nevermind, SpreadsheetVersion#getMaxFunctionArgs will probably do the trick

Comment: @brecht-d-m - in general, a formula cell and a text cell is the same cell. The limitation is put by Excel, whenever there is a formula inside. Thus long story short - probably **No**.